# External frameworks fail notarization even after being codesigned

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, notarize, sparkle

I use the Sparkle lib in my Developer ID MacOS application for auto-updating. I export the app using CLI tools (`xcodebuild`) and then notarize using `xcrun notarytool`, this all seems to work fine.

I then create a DMG, and it's when I notarize this I get around 16 of the following errors:

- "The binary is not signed with a valid Developer ID certificate."
- "The signature does not include a secure timestamp."

I get both of these errors for all of of the following files:

```
"MyApp.dmg/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/B/Sparkle"
"MyApp.dmg/MyApp.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/B/Autoupdate"
"MyApp.dmg/MyApp.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/B/Updater.app/Contents/MacOS/Updater"
"MyApp.dmg/MyApp.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/B/XPCServices/Downloader.xpc/Contents/MacOS/Downloader"
"MyApp.dmg/MyApp.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/B/XPCServices/Installer.xpc/Contents/MacOS/Installer"
```

It seems like the Sparkle apps that are packaged inside my app need to be codesigned before being packaged into a disk image and notarized.

I have tried:

- codesigning the `.dmg` container
- codesigning app with `--deep` flag before notarization
- codesigning app and all sub-apps (listed above) individually
- codesigning app and all sub-apps before notarization

I use the following bash method I created for codesigning:

```
function codesignApp() {
  codesign --force --sign "Developer ID Application: <NAME REDACTED> (<TEAMID REDACTED>)" \
    --timestamp --deep --verbose --options=runtime "$1"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's necessary to notarize the app before building the dmg. Just build and sign the .app, add it to the dmg, sign the dmg and then notarize the dmg. Also - why does your dmg contain the xcarchive? It should only have the app.

Comment: You are correct on both counts. The app notarization was not necessary. I used `create-dmg` to create the image which was putting everything in the directory into the dmg. I deleted the archive before running it and that solved that! Thank you.